# Comparing multiple lists inside of lists

Tags: python

I need some help with my python homework.
Currently, I created 4 lists. I separated items in those lists to create a list from each item. It looks like this (there are 5000 items in one list):

```
[['n', 'AattGNtA', '0.5196'], ['t', 'gnGCTTcC', '0.7973'], ['P', 'GGTcANTN', '0.5197'], etc. ... ]
```

My goal is to try to write a loop which will compare second entry (eg. AattGNtA) of each item between all four lists (second entry of first items in all four lists, second entry of second items in all lists and so on). If this condition is fullfiled, the program should also check if the third entry in each item is higher than 0.2. If sequences are the same and the third entry is larger than 0.2, the program should increment this by count of 1.
At the end, the result should be the total count of items which are the same in all lists (therefore max. 5000).
I tried to write several while loops to perform this but I have difficulties to compare multiple complex lists like that. 
This was my last try, which as all of my previous tries resulted in error (I only tried to compare the second entries so far):

```
all_duplicates = 0
while(True):
    for item[1] in zip(item_list1,item_list2,item_list3,item_list4):
        if item[1]= item[1]
            all_duplicates = all_duplicates + 1
else: pass
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This was the error message which poped up after running the code: File "path", line 74
    if item[1]= item[1]
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['n', 'AattGNtA', '0.5196'], ['t', 'gnGCTTcC', '0.7973'], ['P', 'GGTcANTN', '0.5197']]
columns = list(zip(*data))

duplicates = 0
for index, item in enumerate(columns[1]):
    if columns[1].count(item) > 1 and float(columns[2][index]) > 0.2:
        duplicates += 1
print(duplicates)
```

Comment: May I ask why columns[1].count(item) > 1?

Comment: This returns the number of occurrences of `item` within `columns[1]` (to see if there is a duplicate somewhere).